# DocuSign API Integration Key Workflow

Tags: docusignapi

I just signed up with Docusign for a enterprise account. When I view my API information, I see my Account ID, password and username. From there I went to demo.docusign.com and created a completely separate account to get an integrator key. However, the account ID, password and username for the demo account are completely different from my enterprise account. Should I use my enterprise credentials with the demo integrator key? Or use demo credentials with the demo integrator key?

I've already created several templates and document brands in my enterprise account- I would like to avoid replicating them in the demo account to test them in my application.

Answer (score 2):

You need to setup your workflow in Demo and then go through API Certification to get your Integrator Key promoted to Production.

See the Go Live section for information regarding API Certification: [Here](https://www.docusign.com/developer-center/go-live/overview)

Your DocuSign Account Manager is the correct person to talk to for additional information about this.